When I execute Sharphound.exe it is unable to connect to LDAP
I am pretty new to pentesting and Bloodhound/sharphound.
I have installed and bloodhound and the page is running. Now I want to run Sharphound as an executable but it cannot.
When I run -\SharpHound.exe
I get this error:
LDAP connection is null for filter(objectclass=domain) and domain Default Domain
|ERROR| Unable to connect to LDAP, verify your credentials

I cannot find any solution and I do not know what to do.
I tired googling it but did not find any solutions
